# backtick not working

Tags: bash, backticks

I have a large number of files in a directory structure I want to rename.

The file names are in this format:
"aaaaaa-bbbbbb_cccccc-ddddd_eeeee-fffff-ggggg-hhhhh.psd"

I want them in this format:
"Aaaaaa-Bbbbbb_Cccccc-Ddddd_Eeeee-Fffff-Ggggg-Hhhhh.psd

A single find and sed routine should transform them into the correct format:

```
find . -name "*psd" -exec sh -c "echo 'cp '{} `echo {} | sed 's/\([_-][a-z]\)\([A-Z]*\)/\2\U\1/g'`" \;
```

But it doesn't work:

input:

Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd

output:

cp ./Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd ./Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd

The sed routine works if I remove the backtick and insert a semi-colon.

```
find . -name "*bubbles3.psd" -exec sh -c "echo 'cp '{} ; echo {} | sed 's/\([_-][a-z]\([A-Z]*\)/\2\U\1/g'" \;

cp ./Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd
./Assisted-Or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-Or-Auto_Abstract-Render_Tiny-Bubbles3.psd
```

So, for some reason backtick is not do what it should be doing. Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?
fyi replacing backticks with the " $(cmd) " notation has the same effect

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the shell is interpreting the command inside the backticks first (even before running `find`).  However, "`{}`" won't have any special meaning until *after* `find` runs.  Try creating a shell function or bash script for your command instead of writing it inline.  That should let you do more complex things without worrying about problems with shell escapes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed 's/\([/_-][a-z]\)\([A-Z]*\)/\2\U\1/g'
```

i.e.

```
echo $'./Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd' \
| sed 's/\([/_-][a-z]\)\([A-Z]*\)/\2\U\1/g'
```

**output**

```
./Assisted-Or-Auto/Abstract-Render/Assisted-Or-Auto_Abstract-Render_Tiny-Bubbles3.psd
```

I only added the '/' to match the initial lowercase word-part (and my sed said `mismatched \( .. \)` so I added them 1 in in the logical place.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

slight variation

```
$ input=Assisted-or-Auto/Abstract-Render/assisted-or-auto_abstract-render_tiny-bubbles3.psd
$ sed 's!\(/\|-\|_\)[a-z]!\U&!g' <<< "$input"
Assisted-Or-Auto/Abstract-Render/Assisted-Or-Auto_Abstract-Render_Tiny-Bubbles3.psd
```

can be made a little cleaner with GNU sed

```
$ sed 's!(/|-|_)[a-z]!\U&!g' <<< "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid backticks, as that means you're asking for escaping issues.

As was already pointed out, it is likely that the backticks take effect before the invocation of `find`.

Use `$()`, which can be nested without much escaping trouble and then escape the `$` in `$(command)` so that it will survive the invocation and get passed to `find`. From that point on (assuming that `find` uses a shell - e.g. `$SHELL` - to execute your command) things will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
find . -name "*bubbles3.psd" | 
sed 'h;s/\(^\|[/_-]\)./\U&/g;H;g;s/^/cp -v /;s/\n/ /' |
bash
```

If you want to see the `cp` command prior to execution, just leave off the last pipe `| bash`